# Why sklearn's kNN classifer runs so fast while the number of my training samples and test samples are large

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, knn

According to my understanding, for each test sample, kNN classifier algorithm computes the distances between the current test sample and all the training samples and select a certain number of the closest neighbors, and determine the label for the test sample, then next test sample will be done.

My code is similar to the sample kNN classifier code in the following hyperlink which is very simple:

https://tutorialspoint.dev/computer-science/machine-learning/multiclass-classification-using-scikit-learn

The number of my training samples is 8000, the number of test samples is 1500, the sample dimension is 12.

When I ran the sklearn kNN classifier code, it only took 2 seconds, and the accuracy is good.

I doubted the time spent by sklearn kNN algorithm, so I wrote a simple code to compute the distance between the test sample and all the training samples, and found it is a time-consuming process, even not including the sorting algorithm. The code for distance calculation is as follow:

```
for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X_train.shape[0]):
        ## calculate distances between a test sample and all train samples
        Distance[j,0] = (X_test.iloc[i,0]-X_train.iloc[j,0])*(X_test.iloc[i,0]-X_train.iloc[j,0]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,1]-X_train.iloc[j,1])*(X_test.iloc[i,1]-X_train.iloc[j,1]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,2]-X_train.iloc[j,2])*(X_test.iloc[i,2]-X_train.iloc[j,2]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,3]-X_train.iloc[j,3])*(X_test.iloc[i,3]-X_train.iloc[j,3]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,4]-X_train.iloc[j,4])*(X_test.iloc[i,4]-X_train.iloc[j,4]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,5]-X_train.iloc[j,5])*(X_test.iloc[i,5]-X_train.iloc[j,5]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,6]-X_train.iloc[j,6])*(X_test.iloc[i,6]-X_train.iloc[j,6]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,7]-X_train.iloc[j,7])*(X_test.iloc[i,7]-X_train.iloc[j,7]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,8]-X_train.iloc[j,8])*(X_test.iloc[i,8]-X_train.iloc[j,8]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,9]-X_train.iloc[j,9])*(X_test.iloc[i,9]-X_train.iloc[j,9]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,10]-X_train.iloc[j,10])*(X_test.iloc[i,10]-X_train.iloc[j,10]) + \
                   (X_test.iloc[i,11]-X_train.iloc[j,11])*(X_test.iloc[i,11]-X_train.iloc[j,11])
```

I am not sure if sklearn use the entire training dataset to calculate the k nearest neighbors. If it does, what optimization algorithm is used by sklearn?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, nearest-neighbor search is really time intensive. If you do it naively, you have are at a runtime of O(n^2). Good thing is, that sklearn uses some clever algorithms to circumvent calculating all the distances.

Have a look at the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) and you will see that one parameter is the `algorithm` used for nearest-neighbor search, e.g. [BallTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree). These algorithms speed up the calculation a lot.

On another note, your code is a little inefficient. Instead of calculating each dimension by hand, you could do:

```
((X_test.iloc[i,:] - X_train.iloc[j,:]) ** 2).sum()
```

This takes advantage of pandas' vectorized functions, making it much faster.

Comment: hi tilman151, I tried "algorithm=ball_tree, kd_tree and brute" respectively, there is no significant difference for run time.  I used your code to compute the distance, and it is a little bit faster than my code. I still have a question: given a single test sample, kNN algorithm needs to compute the distances between the test sample and the 8000 training samples, and then selects k nearest neighbors, it is time intensive even though balltree is used. I still doubt sklearn doesn't use the entire training sample.

Comment: With BallTree it does not need to compute all distances at prediction time. It builds the tree at training time and then checks only which leaf of the tree it has to go to. The leaf contains only a small number of training samples that are near to the test sample, so sklearn computes the distance only for them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it seems that I need to study the balltree algorithm.